# traffic accident vs car accident vs road accident

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I learned English has expressions describing accident that is caused by cars. I could not find differences between traffic accident, car accident, and road accident. I want to find the differences. I would appreciate it if you could inform when you find it.

Comment: they would mostly be used interchangeably, but a road accident could conceivably not involve cars (for example: "the earthquake caused a road accident" but not  "the earthquake caused a car/traffic accident")

Comment: A traffic accident takes place in traffic. A vehicle hitting a pedestrian on an isolated road would not usefully be described as a traffic accident, although it might be a road accident. Two electric scooters colliding might also constitute a road accident. Car accidents involve cars (rather than trucks or vans). One chooses the expression that best suits the context.

Comment: The UK police just say "RTA" (Road Traffic Accident) on the radio and in notes, records, etc. An RTA is "an accident resulting in bodily injury to any person or damage to property caused by, or arising out of, the use of a motor vehicle on a road or other public place."

Comment: I see no scope for any significant difference in ***meaning***, so all you need to do is look at [***this NGram***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+a+traffic+accident%2Cin+a+car+accident%2Cin+a+road+accident%2Cin+a+road+traffic+accident&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20traffic%20accident%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20car%20accident%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20road%20accident%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20a%20road%20traffic%20accident%3B%2Cc0) to see that ***a car accident*** is the overwhelmingly favoured option here.

Comment: car accidents involve cars. There are other vehicles that can have accidents: trucks AKA lorries in the UK, motorcycles,  even tractors (near farms).  All of those can have accidents. They may or may not be in or near traffic. They are most likely in or on a road.